# Create time index R

Tags: r, time, grouping

I am seeking a way create a time index for dates that can be easily manipulated and changed. Namely to turn the data below into buckets for every 3 days(or 4, 5 , etc.

SO that in below example

- 8/1, 8/2 , 8/3 = time index(1)
- 8/4, 8/5, 8/6 = time index(2)
- 8/7,8/8,8/9 = time index(3)

etc

Appreciate any help from the best community :)

Thank you :)

Comment: As a start to generate a sequence of every 3 days use: `seq(as.Date("2018-08-01"), as.Date("2018-09-01"), "3 day")`

Comment: huge help, advice on how to mutate this onto  a new column based off column x?

Comment: also there can be repeat dates, so 8/2 can happen 5 times etc. I want to then group them by the new time index created

Comment: With the line date sequence above you can then use the `cut` function to bin the dates into the separate buckets.  Without a sample of your data (see the dput function) and a description of the desire output it is difficult to go into specifics.